# HTML5 video tag not displaying mp4 video in Microsoft Edge - "This type of video file isn't supported"

Tags: html, video, microsoft-edge

I have a simple HTML5 video tag in a website.

> <video id="myVideo" controls="controls">
>
> <source src="MyVideoPath/MyVideoFileName.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
>
> </video>

It plays the video fine when I use Chrome, Firefox and Internet Explorer, but on Edge the video is black and the text "This type of video file isn't supported" is displayed.

If I navigate directly to the video source on Edge then the video plays perfectly, so I don't think the video's media type is the problem.

What am I missing in my code? Is there some sort of library or plugin I need to reference to display mp4 videos on Edge?

Comment: for the video ... can you post a sample? it may be an encoding issue, also check that your server is giving the correct MIME type (can sometimes get funny about that). just as a note you only need `controls` as it's a boolean (if it's present, they're shown, if not, they don't appear).

Comment: @Offbeatmammal HTML5 in HTML serialization can use `controls`. HTML5 in XML serialization must use `controls="controls"`. Given the use of `/>` closing tags, this appears to be a fragment of an XML serialization.